# Chinese Remainder Theorem result varies

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Sorry if this question is lame. First post!

I was going through this book

> Abstract Algebra
>   Theory and Applications
>   Thomas W. Judson
>   Stephen F. Austin State University

In the Chapter 16. Ring Theory the author explains about how Chinese Remainder Theorem can be used to schedule work to Multi-Processor systems in case of Large Integer Calculations.

In a particular example of calculating 2134*1531. He broke it down to this:

x≡ 9 (mod 95)
x≡ 0 (mod 97)
x≡ 30 (mod 98)
x≡ 55 (mod 99)

The result should be 3,267,154. I used two online calculators [Calc 1](http://www.mathcelebrity.com/chinese.php?matrix1=x%20=%209%20mod%2095%0D%0Ax%20=%200%20mod%2097%0D%0Ax%20=%2030%20mod%2098%0D%0Ax%20=%2055%20mod%2099%0D%0A&pl=Solve%20using%20Chinese%20Remainder%20Theorem) and [Calc 2](http://davidwees.com/chineseremaindertheorem/) and to solve this. Both are giving different and wrong answers 2774788984 and 111543404 respectively. Is there a short and easy way to calculate this?. What is wrong with those calculators?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure these different answers are not all congruent modulo $95\cdot97\cdot98\cdot99$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm has hit the nail on the head. I just checked the first one, but it is indeed giving a value larger than $95\cdot 97\cdot 99\cdot 99$ and congruent to $3267154$. It's not clear why that calculator doesn't reduce the result.

Comment: $11154340 \bmod 98$ is $0$, not $30$. Did you mistype the input, perhaps?

Comment: @HenningMakholm,Peter
Yeah, looks like the first calculator has some problems.

Comment: @HenningMakholm,

2134 ≡ 76 (mod 98),  

1531 ≡ 61 (mod 98),     

So: 2134 · 1531 ≡ 76 · 61 ≡ 30 (mod 98)

111543404 is not the right result.

Comment: @Jay: I wouldn't say it "has problems", since it actually does give a valid solution to the four equations you put in. It's just not the _smallest_ (nonnegative) solution.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, yes. You're right.

Comment: @Jay, that's what I'm saying -- 111543404 is not the right result, but it does satisfy three of your four equations and is only a single missed keypress from satisfying the last one. I'm suggesting that you mistyped the input to calc-2 as `x=0 mod 98` instead of `x=30 mod 98`.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I rechecked. My input is correct. It's giving the same result for both `x≡0 mod 98` as well as `x≡30 mod 98`

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I can reproduce the value given with calc 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with calc1 is simply that it doesn't reduce the result modulo the product $95 \cdot 97 \cdot 98 \cdot 99$

The problem with calc2 isn't mathematical at all. It uses a couple of regexes to parse the input, and the second one is buggy: `/=([0-9])*mod/` rather than `/=([0-9]*)mod/`. This means that it loses all but the last character of the given number, so it reduces the last two congruences to $x \equiv 0 \pmod{98}$ and $x \equiv 5 \pmod{99}$

Edit: David Wees has now fixed the regex bug (that was fast!) and calc2 now gives 2685385054 which is congruent to the expected answer.

Comment: I have sent a message through the contact page on calc2's site to notify the webmaster.

Answer (score 4):

I've modified the calculator as described. It does look like a bug. I guess I only tested it with single digit numbers, which does seem a bit dumb... mind you I haven't really looked at it since I coded it a few years ago. So to answer your question, the problem with the calculators is that they have a bug in them as described by the comment above and the creators of the calculators have probably moved onto other projects.

Thanks for letting me know about the fix.

Comment: Whoa!. @David this is just awesome!. Thanks for fixing it.